# HTML2PDF and api.qrserver.com ERROR number 6

Tags: php, qr-code, html2pdf

I'm trying to output a pdf with a qrCode image in it.
I'm using api.qrserver.com to create the image and HTML2PDF to create the pdf.
This is my PHP code :

```
    $pre_path = 'http://m.website.fr/';
    $path = $pre_path . drupal_lookup_path('alias', "node/" . $_GET['nid']);
    require(drupal_get_path('module', 'pdfcreator') . '/libs/html2pdf_v4.03/html2pdf.class.php');


    ob_clean();

    ob_start();
    require(drupal_get_path('module', 'qrcode') . '/templates/pdf.tpl.php');

    $content = ob_get_clean();
    try {
        $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
       // $html2pdf->setTestIsImage(false);
        $html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);

        $html2pdf->Output($fields['ref'] . date('ymd') . '.pdf', 'D');
    } catch (HTML2PDF_exception $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit;
    }
```

my template pdf.tpl.php contains

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?format=gif&data=<?php echo urlencode($path) ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Without using html2pdf the image is generating just fine. But when I use HTML2PDF I received

Error 6 : unable to load image https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?format=gif&data=http%3A%2F%2Fm.website.fr%2Ffoo%2Fstuff

What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the "s" in https://